# How to protect sumbersible pump ‘pumpsaver’ device

Tags: electrical, pump, lightning

I have a 600 ft well and submersible pump in a mountain home at 9500 ft elevation prone to lightning storms.  I typically have to replace the ‘pump protector’ relay (i.e., protects pump from either high or low amps, e.g., dry well) at least annually.  I’m almost certain the failures are due to lightning strikes nearby.  But my home has lightning rods, whole-house surge protector, and most failures have occurred when pump is not running or even the incoming power disconnect has been turned off.   So I think the power surge which is frying the protective relay is backfeeding from the well.   I’m considering installing an isolation contactor inbetween the pumpprotector relay and wiring going to pump.  Does anyone have a better solution or know of a reason to not install the isolation contactor on all three wires?

Comment: How far away from the surge-protected panel is the wellhead? Is any part of this run out of doors?

Comment: The wellhead is approximately 100 ft from the surge protected panel.    Much of the run is underground, buried approximately 8’ ft deep along with water line to wellhead.

Comment: Does the run come back to the surface at the wellhead, or is the whole shebang buried under the frost line?

Comment: I do think the wiring comes to the surface, and then right back down to ~8 ft below surface as it buried in the same trench as the water line.

Comment: I take it the run out to the pump is 2 hots and a ground (no neutral)?

Comment: Standard modern wellhead (where the top of the well is not hidden underground) is for the pitless adapter to take water out below frost line, but the submersible pump wire goes up conduit on the outside of the well casing into the wellhead, and then back down inside the well casing to the pump.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using copper water line to the well just make sure the pipe is bonded to the well casing and your house electrical ground.
If it's plastic water line than you might want to bury a #6 bare copper bonding jumper and connect it to the house ground to equalize the potential between the two grounds.

Answer (score 1):

Put a "whole-house type" surge suppressor on the well circuit (between the pump and the "protector.") That will always be engaged (whether or not the pump is running) and will clamp surges from the well side, if any.

Verify that you have a solid ground connection between the well casing and your system ground.

I can't prove a negative, but I have a box at my wellhead (110 feet away) with a surge capacitor (CA302R) and a lighting arrestor (LA302R), a box inside on the power feed to the pump relay with another set of the same items, and a rather massive ground cable to the well casing, and I've had no troubles. I'm actually more concerned for the pump, given that it's a pain to pull that thing up out of the well, but the systems logic applies anyway - if voltage is induced on the cables while the pump is off, the set at the wellhead takes that. The set inside takes anything coming from the powerline, or they both do if the pump is running.